# NVARCHAR to DATE (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with the `week_date` stored as `nvarchar(60)`. When I tried to change that to `date`, I'm getting below error.

Records in the table are in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

```
WEEK_DATE
----------
2017-12-31
2018-01-01
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have used the below to convert, but that throws an error

```
SET WEEK_DATE = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(260), WEEK_DATE, 120)
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the data type of this column? Can you clarify what is actually in the table is it `(yyyy-mm-dd) format WEEK_DATE 2017-12-31 2018-01-01` or is it `WEEK_DATE 2017-12-31 2018-01-01`??

Comment: What are you trying to change the value to?  It is already in a reasonable format -- or a string representing a date.

Comment: Thanks, the WEEK_DATE column is in the nvarchar and need to chage the column to date, as i would like insert from another table and that table has date and when i tried to insert date value into the WEEK_DATE .Getting below error Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: You are converting it to a NVARCHAR, not a DATE in your expression.

Comment: hi Nick, i am trying to convert the column from nvarchar to date

Comment: Just saying.. your expression does not do that. Take a look at the `CONVERT` definition - the first argument is what you want to convert to - so this should be `date` or `datetime` - please post the version of SQL Server

Comment: If you still get that error, then there is some incorrectly formatted data in your table, which is a consequence of not using the correct data type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try_convert()` to find the bad values:

```
select datecol
from t
where try_convert(date, datecol) is null and datecol is not null;
```

You can use `try_convert()` in your code, but you should investigate the data problem.

EDIT:

To change the column to a date, first verify the format (so you don't get an error with the conversion):

```
update t
     set week_date = try_convert(date, week_date);
```

Don't worry about the format.  It will use whatever the localization settings are.  But happily, the resulting string will automatically be converted back to a date.

Then, alter the table:

```
alter table t
     alter week_date date;
```

You might want to use the first query to check that all dates strings are actually recognized.

Comment: Thanks, i getting this error Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @MSM . . . It is available in SQL Server since version 2012.  In any case, if you know the values are correct, you can just do the `alter table`.